# XDocument XElement Constructor

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I'm trying to build out a dynamic XDoc which contains a list of Folders that a tool uses as a "path". Each "Folder" element is another layer in the tree

Example:

```
Root Level

 -- Folder L0

      -- Folder L1

         -- Folder L2
```

Which is expressed in the XML as follows:

```
<FolderPath>
   <Folder>L0</Folder>
   <Folder>L1</Folder>
   <Folder>L2</Folder>
</FolderPath>
```

My code is as follows:

```
        // Build up the innermost folders inside the Folderpath element dynamically         
        XElement folderPath = new XElement();
        folderPath.Add(new XElement(FolderList[0],
            new XAttribute("fromDate", FromDate),
            //attributes for Folder w/ lots of attributes
            new XAttribute("toDate", ToDate),
            new XAttribute("contactName", ContactName),
            new XAttribute("email", Email),
            FolderList[0]));

        for (int i = 1; i < FolderList.Count; i++)
        {
            folderPath.Add(new XElement(FolderList[i]));
        }
```

FolderList is a List that I populate prior to this point in the code. However I'm having issues with the line:

```
XElement folderPath = new XElement();
```

What is a good way to implement the XElement so that I can dynamically add the folders contained in FolderList? The error I'm getting is "System.Xml.Linq.XElement does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments".

Comment: This is almost a year old but I came across it while looking up some XElement answers, did you still need any help with this? If you have an example of how you want the resulting XML to look, I can figure out something that would work.

Answer (score 1):

There is `no parameter-less constructor` in XElement class  you should  initialize it like this for example

```
XElement xFolderPath = new XElement("FolderPath");
```

it accepts string as it can be `implicitly`  converted to  `XName`

another tricky way  to overcome your issue is to define `xFolderPath` object instance

Comment: Nice one @JulieShannon.

Answer (score 0):

`XElement` does not have a parameter-less constructor. The constructor you would want to use requires an XName to assign to the XElement, and optionally, you can pass the content of that `XElement` as well.

You can see in the code below where the `XElement` folderPath variable is created, I'm using the `XElement(XName name, params object[] content)`, where you pass the name of the `XElement`, and in this case, I'm passing an array of `XAttribute` objects as it's content.

After that, I created a temporary `XElement` object called previousNode, and assigned the folderPath object to it.

In the for loop, I'm creating a new `XElement` called newNode with the `XElement(XName name)` constructor, and adding it as content to the previousNode `XElement`, then setting the previousNode as the newly created newNode, so any additional elements will be added as children of that `XElement`, creating the hierarchy that I'm assuming you wanted, which is shown below the code sample.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace CommandLineProgram
{
    public class DefaultProgram
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<String> FolderList = new List<string>() { "L0", "L1", "L2" };
            DateTime FromDate = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime ToDate = DateTime.Now;
            String ContactName = "ContactName";
            String Email = "contact@email.com";

            XElement folderPath = new XElement(FolderList[0],
                new XAttribute("fromDate", FromDate),
                //attributes for Folder w/ lots of attributes
                new XAttribute("toDate", ToDate),
                new XAttribute("contactName", ContactName),
                new XAttribute("email", Email));

            XElement previousNode = folderPath;
            for (int i = 1; i < FolderList.Count; i++)
            {
                XElement newNode = new XElement(FolderList[i]);
                previousNode.Add(newNode);
                previousNode = newNode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## folderPath.ToString() output

```xml
<L0 fromDate="2015-03-23T16:13:52.6702528-05:00" 
    toDate="2015-03-23T16:13:52.6702528-05:00" 
    contactName="ContactName" 
    email="contact@email.com">
  <L1>
    <L2 />
  </L1>
</L0>
```